# Compression Algorithm Magic Signatures

Tags: compression

What is the meaning of "magic signature" in reference to data compression algorithms?  For example: http://disktype.sourceforge.net/doc/ch03s15.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File signatures, usually two or several leading bytes, are used in many file formats -- not just compressed data.  They are there for the software asked to process the data to be able to check that they were fed the correct input.  That way, for example, gzip can tell immediately that it wasn't given a gzip file (say it was given a bzip2 file).  Then it can stop immediately and give a useful error message that this isn't a gzip file.  As opposed to detecting the problem later and giving some sort of cryptic message like "invalid bit lengths sequence".

The eight-byte PNG signature was designed not only to identify PNG files, but also to detect common errors such as end-of-line conversions inadvertently applied to the binary PNG file.  The PNG signature contains end-of-line sequences that would be messed with and make it not a PNG signature, providing an early indication of file corruption that would otherwise be detected later, again with a rather more cryptic message.

See this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) for a good list of signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Those are bytes at the begining of the compressed stream identifying the compressor used. For example bzip2 will have the characters 'BZ' at the beginning (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) in section File Format) while gzip will have the bytes 1F 8B. See http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html for more info regarding other file types.

Comment: Do they serve a purpose beyond making it easy to identify the type of compression used, when it's time to de-compress?

Comment: Well, not that I know of... I could say more generally that it is used for identifying the content type.